# Python BeautifulSoup to get Images, Texts, and URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the following url (http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html). So each Hebrew word section starts with img urls followed by 2 texts, the actual hebrew word and its pronunciation. For example the first entry in the url is the following "img1 img2 img3 אֶלֶף e-leph " the hebrew word is a unicode after downloading the html using wget

The following code I have gives me for example `<img src="../../files/heb-anc-sm-pey.jpg"/>` and `<font face="arial" size="+1"> unicode_hebrew_text   </font>` and `<a href="audio/   505 .mp3"><img border="0" height="25" src="../../files/icon_audio.gif" width="25"/></a>`

instead I just want `../../files/heb-anc-sm-pey.jpg`
and `unicode_hebrew_text` and `audio/505.mp3 (without any spaces in between)`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw_html = open('/Users/gansaikhanshur/TESTING/webScraping/1000.html').read()
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

# output: <img src="../../files/heb-anc-sm-pey.jpg"/>
imgs = html.findAll("img")
for image in imgs:
    # print image source
    if "jpg" in str(image):
        print(image)

# output: <font face="arial" size="+1"> unicode_hebrew_text </font>
font = html('font', face="arial", size="+1")
for f in font:
    continue

# output: <a href="audio/   505 .mp3"><img border="0" height="25" src="../../files/icon_audio.gif" width="25"/></a>
mp3file = html.findAll(href=True)
for mp3 in mp3file:
    if "mp3" in str(mp3):
        continue
```

As you can see my code doesn't really do the job. In the end I would like to get information for every word in the URL and save it as a text file or a json file whichever is the easiers.

For example, images: URLsOfImages, HebrewWord: txt, Pronunciation: txt, URLtoAudio: txt

and for the next word and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage that you wish to scrape is a bit tricky.

Now, why do I say so? The thing is, webpage doesn't make much use of div tags or something similar to place the individual Hebrew word and it's related data in a block (let me call the Hebrew word & it's related data, a Hebrew block over here). However, if you focus on the page source, then you'll notice that each Hebrew block starts from a anchor tag which looks something like this : `<a name="505"></a>`. The value '505' will vary as per the strong number of each Hebrew block. So, I tried making this as the starting point of each Hebrew block. Now within the Hebrew block you can use the speaker icon `<a href="audio/    505 .mp3"><img src="../../files/icon_audio.gif" width="25" height="25" border="0"></a>` to denote the ending point of the Hebrew block.

Keeping the above idea in mind, I came up with this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import NavigableString, Tag 
import requests
import re

def make_soup(url):
    html = requests.get(url, verify = False)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup


url = "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html"
soup = make_soup(url)

points = soup.find_all("a", attrs = {"name" : re.compile("[0-9]+")}) 
#This will help you locate the starting points of the Hebrew block

for point in points:
    point_name = point['name'] 
    images = [] #Will hold the links for the Old Hebrew images
    text = "" #Will hold the immediate next Unicode Hebrew text
    usage = "" #Will hold the usage/meaning data
    mp3 = "" #Will hold the link to audio file

    temp = point.next_sibling 
    #'temp' variable will be used as a navigator to extract the data within the Hebrew block 

    while(True):
        #If 'temp' is a HTML 'Tag' by nature, then it'll contain the Unicode Hebrew text and links for images& audio
        if(type(temp) is Tag): 
            if(temp.name == 'img'):        
                #If it's an 'img' tag, then put it to 'images' list 
                images.append(temp['src'])
            elif(temp.name == 'font'):
                #If it's a 'font' tag, then put it in 'text'
                text = temp.string
            elif(temp.name == 'a'):
                #If it's 'a' tag, then it contains the link to audio file
                mp3 = temp['href']  
                #Link to audio file will mark the end of the Hebrew block. So, 'break' out
                break
        elif(type(temp) is NavigableString):
            #If 'temp' acquires a 'NavigableString' instead of a 'Tag' then it's usage/meaning
            usage += temp
        #Move to the next item within the Hebrew block
        temp = temp.next_sibling

    print([point_name, images, mp3, text, usage])
```